# How to measure the performance of a default copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

I would like to know how much time my program is spending in the default copy constructor of a particular class. Is there a way to implement the copy constructor in a way that is identical to the way the default copy constructor would be implemented by the compiler, but with the addition of some instrumentation code that checks the current time before and after running the main body of the constructor?

Comment: Write your own copy constructor and compare the time that takes with the default. But if the default does a correct copy, I can't see how your own implementation could be faster.

Comment: In C++11, use delegating constructors, where you add a custom constructor that has instrumenting logic and delegates to the normal copy constructor. Otherwise, just let the compiler generate the default copy constructor normally, and then use an external profiler that instruments the code dynamically at runtime instead of you writing code for it.

Comment: Ordinarily I would expect a profiler to be able to give you information about the generated copy constructor, unless the copy constructor is being inlined. Are you working on a platform where a traditional profiler is hard to come by?

Answer (score 0):

Use gprof or another profiler.
You can of course write your own timing loops, but the C++ compiler can optimise very aggressively, which makes things difficult. A proper profiler will tell you exactly where the program is spending its time.